# How many Lunar Module Ascent Engines were produced? How many still exist?

Tags: the-moon, engines, ascent

I know of two LM Ascent Engines still in existence.  I believe Grumman built 13 Lunar modules.  I also think at least 5 engines were tested at White Sands.  So that is 18 that were built at a minimum.  But I suspect more were made for testing.  The LM that made it to space did not return so they are gone.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Lunar_Module). 15 LMs were build, 10 were flown.

Answer (score 12):

Things that don't count, but could be confused for engines:

- Four "breadboard articles" BA-1 to BA-4 were built as prototypes of the plumbing.  Three of these were used to feed engines during testing on HA-1 to HA-3.
- PRA-1 to PRA-6 were more advanced plumbing prototypes used on PA-1.
- HA-1 to HA-4 were "test rigs" in which ascent engines could be mounted for testing.  HA-3 was used at White Sands for firing tests.
- PA-1 was a test rig used at White Sands to test a complete setup of ascent engine, RCS quads, and their tankage and plumbing.
- LTA-1 to LTA-8 were "lunar test articles".  Tests included fit checks, vibration, thermal limits, vacuum chamber, electrical compatibility, and electromagnetic interference.  LTA-2 flew unmanned on a test flight of the Saturn V booster.  LTA-5 was used as a test rig at White Sands.

Actual engines:

> With flight-qualified engines, 57 tests were conducted over a total firing time of 3392 seconds.  Five engines [LM-1 to LM-5] and six thrust chambers (three heavyweight and three lightweight) were used.

- LM-1 was used in a lot of testing at White Sands, and then flew unmanned in LEO on Apollo 5.  Burned up in Earth's atmosphere.
- LM-2 was tested at White Sands, then drop-tested.  It's now the LM on display at the Smithsonian.
- LM-3 was used in a lot of testing at White Sands, and then flew manned in LEO on Apollo 9.  Burned up in Earth's atmosphere.
- LM-4 was tested at White Sands, then flown in the "practice landing" of Apollo 10.  It is now somewhere orbiting the sun (exists, but exact location unknown).
- LM-5 was tested at White Sands, then flew on the first moon landing, Apollo 11.  Crashed in an unknown location on the moon.
- LM-6 was used on Apollo 12.  Deliberately crashed into the moon.
- LM-7 became Apollo 13's "lifeboat".  Burned up in Earth's atmosphere.
- LM-8 was used on Apollo 14.  Deliberately crashed into the moon.
- LM-9 was never used.  It's now the LM on display at Kennedy Space Center.
- LM-10 was used on Apollo 15.  Deliberately crashed into the moon.
- LM-11 was used on Apollo 16.  Deliberately crashed into the moon.
- LM-12 was used on Apollo 17.  Deliberately crashed into the moon.
- LM-13 was supposed to be used for Apollo 18.  It's now on display in Long Island, NY.
- LM-14 had a complete ascent engine, but the rest of the vehicle was never completed for Apollo 19.  Available.
- Some parts of LM-15 for Apollo 20 were produced, but not a complete ascent engine.

So 19 complete engines produced, 5 still in existence, 4 on Earth.

Source: [*Apollo Experience Report: Ascent Propulsion System*](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19730010173).

Comment: hmm, interesting